# How to get the rowIndex of a div element clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to get the rowIndex of the `<div>` I clicked.

```
<div id="parent" onClick="this.click()">
    <div id="1">
      <span text="22"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="2"><span text="32"></span></div>
    <div id="3"><span text="232"></span></div>
    <div id="4"><span text="242"></span></div>
    <div id="5"><span text="252"></span></div>
</div>
```

I'm at a stage where I get the `<div>` I have clicked, lets say I have:

```
<div id="3"><span text="232"></div>
```

How can I get the id and the value of the text in the `<span>` inside that `<div>`?

Comment: What is the id/class of the container? How do you add the event handler? Please add the relevant code.

Comment: row index without table?

Comment: What do you call a row ID? If these `div`s are dynamically added, you probably need a counter in your code. If your remove `div`s as well, you need a hash.

Comment: From your example it looks like the `id` matches the "index" of the `div`, but you say you can't use the `id`. Why?

Comment: I'm going to make some assumptions based on the little information provided. You have a parent container around all of those divs and you have added a click event to that container.

You get an event from the click event and should be able to tell which element was clicked by looking at `event.target.id`

Comment: @Herohtar: there can be a case where div is generated like: <div id="id-677"></div><div id="is-566"></div> I'm not sure if I can use the id in this case, but if its possible to detect the value inside it, I'm ok using "id" as a key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the index of an element in a nodeList/HTML Collection on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068955/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-nodelist-html-collection-on-click)

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more precise on why I'm looking to get the id of the div. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event handler to the container (`#parent`) using [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). When the handler is triggered, check if the event target is a span [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

If it is, get the `id` from the parent node (the div), and the text attribute from the span, using [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
var container = document.getElementById('parent');

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('#parent > div > span')) return;
  
  var id = e.target.parentNode.id;
  var text = e.target.getAttribute('text');
  
  console.log(id, text);
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="1">
    <span text="22">1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="2"><span text="32">2</span></div>
  <div id="3"><span text="232">3</span></div>
  <div id="4"><span text="242">4</span></div>
  <div id="5"><span text="252">5</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Jquery**, this will work **[Tested]**:

```
$("#parent").find('span').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

Let me know if any issues with this